# Control volume of player - crackling noise

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

I want that my spaceship gets louder when my mouse moves away from it (and vice versa). Problem is that my function produces an annoying crackling sound I can't get rid of when I move my mouse away from it (and vice versa). The sound file is ok so far. What can I try next?

```
shipSpeed = (abs(player.x - playerPrevPt.x) + abs(player.y - playerPrevPt.y)) / 2;//the ship's speed gets calculated
            
//this is used to determine whether the ship's volume of its sound shall be increased or decreased
if (shipSpeedPrev < shipSpeed) {
    sndManager.increaseSound(Main.SOUND_BACKGROUND, false, .01);
    } else if (shipSpeedPrev > shipSpeed) {
    sndManager.decreaseSound(Main.SOUND_BACKGROUND, false, .01);
    } else if (shipSpeedPrev == shipSpeed) {
    
    } else {
    
}
            
shipSpeedPrev = (abs(player.x - playerPrevPt.x) + abs(player.y - playerPrevPt.y)) / 2;//this is another ship speed so I can compare them
```

//the decreaseSound-function is almost the same

```
public function increaseSound(soundName:String, isSoundTrack:Boolean = false, steps:Number = .1, targetVol:Number = 1):void {
        if (isSoundTrack) {
            if (soundTrackChannel != null) {
                musicVolumeAdj.volume += steps;
                if (musicVolumeAdj.volume >= targetVol) {
                    musicVolumeAdj.volume = targetVol;
                }
                soundTrackChannel.soundTransform = musicVolumeAdj;
            }
        } else {
            soundVolumeAdj = new SoundTransform(incrSndVal, 0);
            incrSndVal += steps;
            soundVolumeAdj.volume += incrSndVal;
            if (soundVolumeAdj.volume >= 1) {
                soundVolumeAdj.volume = 1;
            }
            soundChannels[soundName].soundTransform = soundVolumeAdj;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the audio ends up being [clipped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_clipping) when you increase the volume. Try to find out at what volume the clipping occurs, and then change your function so that it doesn't got beyond that volume.

Perhaps you could also re-author the audio file and reduce the overall volume, so that you can increase it more from your game.